# Pinterest secret board pins to slack

Tags: pinterest, slack-api

I'm new to stackoverflow (though it has given me many answers while coding on wordpress). I have been researching about Pinterest API but, unfortunately, I am not very familiar with APIs in general. I am trying to learn, though. Thus, excuse me and correct me if my approach is wrong.

Some friends and I are sharing a pinterest account for inspiration for some projects we have in common. We have created several secret boards because it is just for us to work. We all log in from our laptops or phones, tablets, and pin images to the boards or review them. We would like our boards to remain secret.
Also, we are starting to use slack to communicate. Even though pinterest proves very useful for us as a bookmarking tool, we are not always aware of what others have pinned. Sometimes we send an email to tell each other, but it is not very useful, specially when it comes to searching those emails when some time has passed.

That's why I was thinking about making a service to send notifications to slack everytime a new pin is pinned to any of the secret boards. This is the basic idea. It could be that every pin sends a notification to a slack channel or depending on which secret board the pin is pinned to the notification is sent to this or that channel.

I have tried IFTTT and Zapier and both work fine with public boards. I have been trying this other service but, as I said, I don't really know how APIs work
http://slack.datastack.co/

So, first of all, is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? If so, could anyone guide? Thank yo very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Pinterest does not (as of yet) provide an API for secret boards and thus can't be integrated with Slack.

Comment: Is this still applicable? If so, do you know if Pinterest has plans to make secret boards accessible via the API?

Comment: i'd like to get some updates as well. any news on that side ?